# Importing XML to SQL with one element coppied to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Lets say I have many XML files to import into a new SQL database, each XML file has a varied number of `<book>` branched that will be imported to a new row (I have mostly worked that bit out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634768/parsing-xml-into-sql-with-elements-at-different-levels-of-xml-tree)) but each XML file also has a single `<country>` element that is common for all `<book>`'s in that XML file.

How would read each *.xml file from a folder and get it to import like so:

test1.xml

```
<store>
  <bookstore>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Petes Book of Pie</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Pete P</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
  ...
  <countrycode>
    <country>Australia</country>
  </countrycode>
</store>
```

Test2.xml

```
<store>
  <bookstore>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Gotta Go Fast</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Dr Speed</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>If It Aint Broke</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Mr fixit</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
  ...
  <countrycode>
    <country>USA</country>
  </countrycode>
</store>
```

SQL output:

```
TITLE               AUTHOR          COUNTRY
Harry Potter        J K. Rowling    Australia
Petes Book of Pie   Pete P          Australia
Gotta Go Fast       Dr Speed        USA
If It Aint Broke    Mr fixit        USA
```

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: check if this could be of help to reach answer:

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/XML.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that should get you started. You can run this in SSMS.

```
-- Fetch data from files...
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @Data = BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK 'E:\Temp\test1.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS x;

    SELECT @Data = @Data + BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK 'E:\Temp\test2.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS x;

-- Set @Data into an XML variable with a "root" element.
DECLARE @xml XML = CAST( '<root>' + @Data + '</root>' AS XML );

-- Return the XML results.
SELECT
    doc.fld.value ( 'data(ref_title/title)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) AS [TITLE],
    doc.fld.value ( 'data(ref_author/author)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) AS [AUTHOR],
    doc.fld.value ( 'data(../../countrycode/country)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) AS [COUNTRY]
FROM @xml.nodes( '//root/store/bookstore/book' ) doc ( fld );
```

RETURNS

```
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
|       TITLE       |    AUTHOR    |  COUNTRY  |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| Harry Potter      | J K. Rowling | Australia |
| Petes Book of Pie | Pete P       | Australia |
| Gotta Go Fast     | Dr Speed     | USA       |
| If It Aint Broke  | Mr fixit     | USA       |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

**NOTE:** In order to use OPENROWSET/BULK in this manner, the files (in this case test1.xml and test2.xml) **must** exist on the server where SQL is running and SQL **must** have access to their location.

It's also worth noting that this example implements no error handing in the event the XML is badly formatted or a file is empty. It's just meant as a reference to get you started.

Contents of **test1.xml**

```
<store>
  <bookstore>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Petes Book of Pie</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Pete P</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
  <countrycode>
    <country>Australia</country>
  </countrycode>
</store>
```

Contents of **test2.xml**

```
<store>
  <bookstore>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>Gotta Go Fast</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Dr Speed</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <ref_title>
        <title>If It Aint Broke</title>
      </ref_title>
      <ref_author>
       <author>Mr fixit</author>
      </ref_author>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
  <countrycode>
    <country>USA</country>
  </countrycode>
</store>
```